# Add Framework Support missing in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, faker, intellij-15

I am trying to add an external library using Maven.

Tutorials mention to right click on a module, and select "Add Framework Support". I have looked in detail, and I cannot find that option in my IntelliJ.

Here is my current version of IntelliJ:

[image]

Any insight would be appreciated, as I have been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: Are you sure this feature is available in the Community Edition? Some features are Ultimate only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is in the contextual menu of your project. Right click on the root folder of your project and you will find it.

So you should have already created a project. Or, at a project creation you can also decide to use any framework

[image: framework support]

Comment: That is so strange.  I could have sworn it wasn't there when I tried that.  But it's there, so must have been an oversight 

Answer (score 0):

If you cant get the option after right clicking , what you can do is press Shift Twice and then search Add Framework support and then click . Now you can add the support

Answer (score -1):

Try to download [Hibernate Core Relocation]: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core from Maven repository

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).